# Use localhost domain name FQDN for local web project. Did I need to config my Windows DNS?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, localhost, virtualdirectories

My local Apache service is running perfectly fine. I am running WAMP.

I am trying to configure my .httpd file so that I can access specific projects as fully qualified domain names like: mysite.com ( but resolves to something like localhost/myfoldername/).

I was able to get it working with a different port number like:

```
localhost:8080
```

And `localhost:80` is my root web dir.

Here is my current .httpd config:

`listening: 80` (defined higher in the .httpd)

.... below was added to my .httpd

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>

ServerName www.jobeet.com

DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\symfony\jobeet\web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "C:\wamp\www\symfony\jobeet\web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf C:\wamp\www\symfony\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony-1.4.8\data\web\sf
  <Directory "C:\wamp\www\symfony\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony-1.4.8\data\web\sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my Windows host file config:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1:8080  www.jobeet.com.localhost
```

If anyone has any ideas, please tell me! I've been on this for over 8 hours : ( thx.

Comment: What is wrong?... ping www.jobeet.com.localhost? netstat -n? www.jobeet.com.localhost open in boruser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hosts file only supports translations of IP addresses to names, so the `:8080` is totally unnessesary.

Additionally, because the hosts file is not actually DNS at all, you don't enter any search suffixes, so you should only enter the *entire* domain name. SO dump the `.localhost` from it as well. It should read:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       www.jobeet.com
```

Of course, then you will lose all access to the REAL `www.jobeet.com`, but you can't have it both ways.